# calling a tcl proc in python3

Tags: python-3.x, tcl

I am trying to call a `tcl` `proc` in a `python` program.

The `tcl` script starts with

```
proc scale_wigner-seitz_radii { } {
```

(I am not sure if I can put the full proc here, as this is a part of a licensed program).

This program is called by my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from numpy import arange
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move, copy
from os import remove, close, mkdir, path
import Tkinter


def repll(file_path, pattern, subst):
    print(pattern)
    print(subst)
    print(file_path)
    r = Tkinter.Tk
    # fullpath = str(subst) + "/" + file_path
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    with open(abs_path, "w") as new_file:
        with open(file_path, "r") as old_file:
            for line in old_file:
                new_file.write(line.replace(pattern.strip(),
                                            str(subst).strip()))
    r.tk.eval('source /home/rudra/WORK/xband/create_system_util.tcl')
    r.tk.eval('proc scale_wigner-seitz_radii')
    copy(abs_path, path.join(str(subst), file_path))


inpf = str(sys.argv[1])
a = []
print (inpf)
with open(inpf, "r") as ifile:
    for line in ifile:
        if line.startswith("lattice parameter A"):
            a = next(ifile, "")
            print(a)

for i in arange(float(a)-.10, float(a)+.10, 0.02):
    if not path.exists(str(i)):
        mkdir(str(i))
    repll(inpf, a, i)
```

I havn't make a minimal example, because this seems better than explaining in english.

At the very end of `def repll`, it is calling the `tcl proc`. I have never encountered a tcl script before, and found the calling process from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439936/how-to-call-tcl-procedure-using-python).
But when I am running this, I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xband.py", line 41, in <module>
    repll(inpf, a, i)
  File "xband.py", line 24, in repll
    r.tk.eval('source /home/rudra/WORK/xband/create_system_util.tcl')
AttributeError: class Tk has no attribute 'tk'
```

How I can solve this?

**After Donal's Comment** Thanks for your reply. After following your suggestion, I got same error from `source` line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xband.py", line 41, in <module>
    repll(inpf, a, i)
  File "xband.py", line 24, in repll
    r.tk.eval('/home/rudra/WORK/xband/create_system_util.tcl')
AttributeError: class Tk has no attribute 'tk'
```

Sorry if its silly, but since the tcl is in different file, I must source that first, right? And, as I said, this is the first tcl code I am looking at, please be elaborate.

Comment: You've not hit this bug yet, but `r.tk.eval('proc scale_wigner-seitz_radii')` is wrong. The Tcl `proc` command _defines_ commands; to call them, you just use the command name: `r.tk.eval('scale_wigner-seitz_radii')`. You'll need to sort your other bug out as well (and the fix for that might well also apply here).

Comment: _From a Tcl perspective,_ you have to first `source` the file, then invoke the procedure within it. This can be done in a single script call: `source /home/rudra/WORK/xband/create_system_util.tcl; scale_wigner-seitz_radii` (with a `;` to separate the two command calls). You also need to sort out the Python side of things, where it appears you are calling the `tk` method on the wrong entity. Do you need to instantiate the `Tk` class?

Comment: Hi Donal,
if you have some free time, can I ping you? As I said, since the tcl is a part of licensed code, I am little sceptic to put it public

Comment: I _really_ don't know Python well enough to help you properly. I've given all the Tcl help that you really need already (well, with this particular question anyway). And I tend to have rather busy days during the week…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be this line:

```
r = Tkinter.Tk
```

My guess is, you think this is creating an instance of `Tk`, but you're merely saving a reference to the *class* rather than creating an *instance* of the class. When you instantiate it, the object that gets returned has an attribute named `tk`, which the object internally uses to reference the tcl interpreter. Since you aren't instantiating it, `r` (which points to `Tk`) has no such attribute.

To fix it, instantiate the class by adding parenthesis:

```
r = Tkinter.Tk()
```

`r` will now be a proper reference to a `Tk` object, and should have a `tk` attribute, and with that you can call `eval` on raw tcl code.